# Adding keypress functionality to a div via jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a keypress listener that only listens to a keypress of 'a' and when it's triggered, the background will turn to a transparent white, with its border slightly greyed.

This is what I have, and somehow it's not working.  (Don't mind the other CSS classes, they're just for font decoration)  Can someone show me what I'm not seeing?

```js
$( "#test" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  //I think 97 is the character code for 'a'
  if(event.which == 97){
    $(this).addClass('.test_card');
  }else{
    event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

```css
body{background: black;
}

.card{
  background-color:transparent;
  width:10%;
  margin-left:1.25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: white solid 2px;
  display:inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.test_card{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border: grey solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="card" id="test">
  <h1 class="card__title">A</h1>
  <p class="card__description">
    Snare
  </p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: How would the div get the keyboard focus?

Comment: Imagine you are the browser, how you can determine what div the user is "using". Consider attach your event to `window` or `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.` in `addClass('.test_card')`. Also bind the event to the document and not to the div so that every time you press `a`, the event will fire

```js
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '97') {
    $('#test').addClass('test_card');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 1.25%;
  height: 100%;
  border: white solid 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.test_card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border: grey solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="card" id="test">
    <h1 class="card__title">A</h1>
    <p class="card__description">
      Snare
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *"Actually, it is 65 and not 97"* - It would be 97 in a key *press* listener, which distinguishes between upper and lower case. It would be 65 in a key *down* or *up* handler. Note that the OP was about key *press*.

Comment: @nnnnnn I didn't know about that much, but I changed it and it also worked, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#test").bind("keydown", function( event ) {
      console.log(event.which)
      //I think 97 is the character code for 'a'
      if(event.which == 65){
        $(this).addClass('test_card');
      }else{
        event.preventDefault();
       }
    });

    $('#test').focus();
});
```

add your JS at the bottom of your page to speedup the display of you page. home this helps you :-) happy coding.

jsbin for working code: http://jsbin.com/yecequnade/edit?html,output